# Scatter plots of p-value distribution of gene expression data in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset, scatterplot

How do I distinctly represent two data sets on the same scatter plot , to compare the p-value distributions of the genes using R packages?

The gene expression values and p-values (obtained by ANOVA) of the two datasets are:

```
### data A

    probes     AG1      AG2      LR1       LR2
      901  4.991648  6.289011 5.556497 5.698004
      902  5.465736  6.036498 7.126263 7.004082
      903  8.559740  9.833907 8.567032 8.433505
      904  7.068298  6.156696 6.436085 6.793267
      905  5.388158  4.911885 5.642148 5.914592

### data A (p-value)
    901           902          903          904          905
 8.705207e-01 2.084426e-05 2.313093e-03 2.027818e-01 1.273762e-01 


### data B

        probes  AG1    AG2      LR1     LR2
         901 4.562965 4.917767 4.636715 5.223545
         902 4.662215 4.845352 4.893514 5.139439
         903 5.206248 4.396288 4.274906 5.458326
         904 6.027329 6.169694 6.350698 6.317571
         905 4.981953 4.980007 4.948762 5.118272

### data B(p-value)

   901           902          903          904          905
 3.225798e-01 2.205045e-01 3.957011e-01 7.262735e-01 9.253321e-01
```

I have around 15000 genes to visualize and would like to produce a scatter plot for comparing the p-value distribution in both datasets.

Comment: Why a scatter plot? You're trying to compare distributions. If you had the same number of points you could do a QQ plot, but more generally why not compare, say, cdfs?

Comment: @ Glen_b : thought it was easier to compare between the two datasets and recognize geometric shapes all of which are readily visible in the scatterplots.

Comment: @Glen_b why do you need the same number of points to do a qqplot? The `R` function `qqplot` works fine with unequal number of points and I don't immediately see a reason for this requirement.

Comment: Can't you just assign each set of p-values to a vector and then plot one against the other?

Comment: @ Peter Flom: Yes this was one option I thought of, Just wanted to know if there are other possibilities.

Comment: @PeterFlom Well, yes, it will do it, by interpolating the values of the larger down to the sample size of the smaller. Unless both your samples are sufficiently large this can somewhat alter the pattern of the relationship in somewhat unexpected ways (I guess in a sense it's not all that different from trying to judge a distribution from a single histogram - most of the time it's not too bad but it can have a few hidden surprises, particularly in smaller samples). I'm not convinced that throwing away a lot of information about the bigger sample - then using interpolation - is such a great idea

Comment: Have you tried using a Manhattan Plot?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_plot

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, it does a linear interpolation by default. If the sample sizes are very different and one is small, I could see that this could be problematic. But if either a) Both samples are large (say > 100) or b) The samples are about the same size then not much seems to be lost. If one n = 1000 and one n = 100, then it's like a histogram with 100 bins.

Comment: @PeterFlom +1 - yes, I think that with plenty of observations in the smaller group, the interpolation on the larger would lose little information (indeed, in that situation, interpolation is basically smoothing, so typically\* that would be fine), and a QQ plot is a pretty effective way to compare distributions in that case. ... \* (not too many modes for example)